# run pure java programs inside of a spring boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-scraping

So i am new to spring boot, part of my project is to scrape some websites and then do some operations on the data scraped, spring boot rest is my way to expose my data
I was wondering when and where we can run pure java programs inside of a spring boot project, the only idea that  came to my mind is to call my programs inside of a class that implements CommandLineRunner as follows :

```
public class MyClass implements CommandLineRunner{
     private OtherClassRepository otherClassRepository;
     public MyClass ( OtherClassRepository otherClassRepository ) {
     this.otherClassRepository = otherClassRepository;
   }
     //do operations and webscraping programs already created in other classes
     //guatering the data
   @Override
   public void run ( String... strings ) throws Exception {
     //pass the guethered data to "OtherClass" and then expose
   }
}
```

And of course I have my controllers, repositories and entities.
I would like to know if this is a way to do it and what other ways to get this to work.

Comment: instead of running a command line, can't you call a web service and run the code you want to run ? Of course this depends on what kind of things your code is doing. I use `@Scheduled` for periodic job and ` @Async` for asynchronous code execution. Tell us more about your use case.

Comment: I didn't really get you when you said run the code with a webservice call. As I said in the question i scrap some data using jsoup and it's all working with simple java project, now i need to expose the data i guathered  using rest spring boot that's why i switched totally to a new spring boot project to work in one project and do all the work at once. I hope i was clear enough. Thank you

Comment: How do you trigger you app to scrap a website ? if it is by running a command, then you can do the exact same thing by calling a webservice eg: `curl https://example.com/scrap?website=http://example.com`. And in the code of your controller you can call your "pure java" code.

Comment: I have a java with static method, i run them in a main when i beed a specific function to do a specific scraping

Comment: What i'm trying to say is that nothing stops you from calling your static methods from any spring bean, like `@Controller`,`@RestController` or even a `@Component` bean with a `@Scheduled` annotated method.

Comment: make more sense now, thanks